# Splice Machine: TIMESTAMPADD returns value that is 1 hour off 10-15% of the time

Tags: splice-machine

Running into a weird bug when executing `TIMESTAMPADD` queries where the result is not always accurate.

**Example #1 (incorrect):**

> `TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_SECOND, 1214870399, TIMESTAMP('1970-01-01 00:00:00.000Z'))`
>
> Returns: `2008-07-01 00:59:59.0`
>
> It should be: `2008-06-30 23:59:59.0`

**Example #2 (correct):**

> `TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_SECOND, 1167609600, TIMESTAMP('1970-01-01 00:00:00.000Z'))`
>
> Returns: `2007-01-01 00:00:00.0` which is correct.

It happens with roughly 10-15% of my queries (lots of unixtime to timestamp converting when querying my tables). It is always the same 1 hour off.

Thanks

**Edit with additional information:**

Other example unixtimes that show up incorrectly if I try to convert:

- `1270508410` to `2010-04-06 00:00:10.0` which should be `2010-04-05 23:00:10.0`
- `1304722810` to `2011-05-07 00:00:10.0` which should be `2011-05-06 23:00:10.0`
- `1340221507` to `2012-06-20 20:45:07.0` which should be `2012-06-20 19:45:07.0`

This last one is just to show its not just related to timestamps that are near the midnight time period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Splice Machine has their own open issue about this problem.

For reference when reaching out to Splice Machine support: Ticket number DB-4937